# Access denied in Windows cmd, but working in PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd

Running the following command:

`dir "\\<Some Network Path>\"`

gives this result when executed in a **command prompt (cmd)**:

`Access is denied.`

and this (expected) result when executed in **PowerShell**:

```
    Directory:
    \\<Some Network Path>


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----       13.02.2020     11:11              0 test.txt
```

I know that dir is not the same command in cmd and PowerShell - but I don't understand why it may result in "Access denied" in cmd while working in PowerShell when executed on the same machine with the same user. Also, I can open the folder in Windows Explorer.

What can be possible reasons?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you running cmd as admin?

Comment: No, I'm running both cmd and powershell with the same non-admin user.

Comment: Could you try running as admin?

Comment: Same result... But still, it is a network path, so local admin rights cannot help. Yet, the user *should* have access to that network path, and PowerShell and Windows Explorer proof that.

Comment: "CMD.EXE was started with the above path as the current directory. UNC paths are not supported. Defaulting to Window directory."https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/2c44083d-86d0-450d-b24e-955cfc473872/unc-paths-are-not-supported-error-message-comes-up-is-it-ok-to-ignore?forum=ITCG